# Emerge issue in Gentoo

Tags: configuration, bind, gentoo

I have an issue with my gentoo. I tried to install **BIND** into my gentoo but everytime i want to install it, i will get an error message.

Here is whats happen in my Konsole :

```
emerge --ask net-dns/bind

* IMPORTANT: 3 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
* See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
* man page to learn how to update config files.

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g  USE="-bindist*" 
[ebuild  N     ] net-dns/bind-9.9.4_p2  USE="berkdb dlz gost ipv6 ldap odbc ssl -caps -doc -filter-aaaa -fixed-rrset -geoip -gssapi -idn -mysql -postgres -python -rpz -rrl -sdb-ldap (-selinux) -static-libs -threads -urandom -xml" 

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-libs/openssl:0

 (dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
 >=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.0:0[-bindist] required by (net-dns/bind-9.9.4_p2::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
 dev-libs/openssl:0[-bindist] required by (net-dns/bind-9.9.4_p2::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)

(dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
>=dev-libs/openssl-0.9.6d:0[bindist] required by (net-misc/openssh-5.9_p1-r4::gentoo, installed)


It may be possible to solve this problem by using package.mask to
prevent one of those packages from being selected. However, it is also
possible that conflicting dependencies exist such that they are
impossible to satisfy simultaneously.  If such a conflict exists in
the dependencies of two different packages, then those packages can
not be installed simultaneously. You may want to try a larger value of
the --backtrack option, such as --backtrack=30, in order to see if
that will solve this conflict automatically.

For more information, see MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge man
page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.


!!! The following installed packages are masked:
- media-libs/mesa-9.0::gentoo (masked by: package.mask)
/usr/portage/profiles/package.mask:
# Chí-Thanh Christopher Nguyễn <chithanh@gentoo.org> (26 Mar 2014)
# Affected by multiple vulnerabilities, #445916, #471098 and #472280

For more information, see the MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge
man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

Can anyone show me how to resolve this issue in my Gentoo. I have a hard time to install anything.

**UPDATED**

```
emerge --ask net-dns/bind


* IMPORTANT: 3 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
* See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
* man page to learn how to update config files.

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g  USE="-bindist*" 
[ebuild  N     ] net-dns/bind-9.9.4_p2  USE="berkdb dlz gost ipv6 ldap odbc ssl -caps -doc -filter-aaaa -fixed-rrset -geoip -gssapi -idn -mysql -postgres -python -rpz -rrl -sdb-ldap (-selinux) -static-libs -threads -urandom -xml" 

The following USE changes are necessary to proceed:
see "package.use" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by net-dns/bind-9.9.4_p2[ssl]
# required by net-dns/bind (argument)
=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g -bindist

Use --autounmask-write to write changes to config files (honoring
CONFIG_PROTECT). Carefully examine the list of proposed changes,
paying special attention to mask or keyword changes that may expose
experimental or unstable packages.

!!! The following installed packages are masked:
- media-libs/mesa-9.0::gentoo (masked by: package.mask)
/usr/portage/profiles/package.mask:
# Chí-Thanh Christopher Nguyễn <chithanh@gentoo.org> (26 Mar 2014)
# Affected by multiple vulnerabilities, #445916, #471098 and #472280

For more information, see the MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge
man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

Answer (score 3):

2 steps to solve this problems:

1. package.use/bind

   ```
   net-dns/bind -ipv6 dlz
   dev-libs/openssl -bindist
   net-misc/openssh -bindist
   ```
2. recompile ssl ssh, and install bind

   ```
   emerge -Uav dev-libs/openssl  net-misc/openssh
   emerge -av net-dns/bind
   ```

the uses for bind:

equery uses bind -i

```
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset             ]
 * Found these USE flags for net-dns/bind-9.10.2_p2:
 U I
 + + berkdb   : Add support for sys-libs/db (Berkeley DB
for MySQL)
 + + caps     : Use Linux capabilities library to control
privilege
 + + dlz      : Enables dynamic loaded zones, 3rd party
extension
 - - doc      : Add extra documentation (API, Javadoc,
etc). It is recommended to enable per
package instead of globally
 - - filter-aaaa              : Enable filtering of AAAA records over IPv4
 - - fixed-rrset              : Enables fixed rrset-order option
 - - geoip    : Add geoip support for country and city
lookup based on IPs
 - - gost     : Enables gost OpenSSL engine support
 - - gssapi   : Enable gssapi support
 - - idn      : Enable support for Internationalized Domain
Names
 - - ipv6     : Add support for IP version 6
 - - json     : Enable JSON statistics channel
 - - ldap     : Add LDAP support (Lightweight Directory
Access Protocol)
 - - mysql    : Add mySQL Database support
 - - nslint   : Build and install the nslint util
 - - odbc     : Add ODBC Support (Open DataBase
Connectivity)
 - - postgres : Add support for the postgresql database
 - - python   : Add optional support/bindings for the
Python language
 + + python_targets_python2_7 : Build with Python 2.7
 + + python_targets_python3_3 : Build with Python 3.3
 - - python_targets_python3_4 : Build with Python 3.4
 - - rpz      : Enable response policy rewriting (rpz)
 - - seccomp  : Enable seccomp for system call filtering
 + + ssl      : Add support for Secure Socket Layer
connections
 - - static-libs              : Build static versions of dynamic libraries
as well
 + + threads  : Add threads support for various packages.
Usually pthreads
 - - urandom  : Use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/random
 - - xml      : Add support for XML files
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this help:

```
# vi /etc/portage/package.use
```

and add this line:**(this line was changed)**

```
dev-libs/openssl -bindist
```

I have no other way if it doesn't work, Sorry :(

maybe you can get help from [gentoo forums](http://forums.gentoo.org).

good luck.

Comment: I have tried your codes and still got an error. I updated my question. Can you take a look at it? @songhir

Comment: @Rockster please see the new answer.

Comment: Thanks @songhir . I'll try my best and find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
emerge net-dns/bind --autounmask-write
etc-update
emerge net-dns/bind
```

remove `-bindist` from `USE` flags

Answer (score 0):

Just to help other people having the same error, you need add the line under "# Required by" to your package.use file.

```
echo "=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g -bindist" >> /etc/portage/package.use/zz-autounmask
```

or

```
nano -w /etc/portage/package.use/zz-autounmask
```

and then manually copy the line into the file.

Replace "=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.1g -bindist" with what's required to be added to your package.use